# Picture viewer for OS X fast and good handling

Tags: osx, image-viewer

I have following problem in OS X:

I want to open a picture file from finder, view it immediately fullscreen and skip to the next image with one click. And this picture viewer needs to be fast.

I've evaluated a lot of picture viewers but non of them is good at all my needs like speed & handling.

Top 3 so far:

- Xee3, best handling but slow with big pictures
- Acdsee for OS X, fastest speed but I have to open their browser once before I can skip to the next image (annoying)
- Preview (build in to OS X), fast but handling very annoying. I have to select all pictures I want to open in future before I can skip to next picture.

Is there any picture viewer I  missed?

Comment: if the files are in a single folder you can select all files (cmd-a) and just double click on one.  They will all open at once and you can view them in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [qView](https://intvhq.com/qview/) would work for you

- Easy to grab and zoom images
- Go to the next and previous file with the arrow keys
- Opens images quickly and scales them appropriately
- Free, open source, and cross-platform

[image]

Comment: that looks cool. I will definitely check it out... hopefully I have a final answer for this problem ;)

Comment: I checked your image viewer out. It's nearly perfect except the zooming behaviour. I made a ticket [here](https://github.com/jeep70/qView/issues/170). Nevertheless I mark this question as answered ;)

Answer (score 1):

[GraphicConverter](https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/) lets you open a directory of images (even nested directories) and view them in various configurations (full screen, full screen with dock, grid; various options for advancing- mouse, keyboard, automatic). It's been under active development since 1992 so it's very fast and well-supported.

Answer (score 1):

#### [XnView MP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/)

Works very well for me on Yosemite 10.10.5 MacBook. I believe it fulfills all requirements.

[image: XnView MP]